# I have an error trying to run my sqoop job (trying to copy a table from oracle to hive)

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am trying to copy a table from oracle to hadoop (hive) with a sqoop script (the table does not already exist in hive). Within putty, I launch a script called "**my_script.sh**", code sample below.  However, after I run it, it gives me back my code followed by `no such file or directory` error. Can someone please tell me if I am missing something from my code?

Yes my source and target directory is correct (I made sure to triple check).

Thank you

```
#!/bin/bash

sqoop import \
-Dmapred.map.child.java.opts='-Doracle.net.tns_admin=. -Doracle.net.wallet_location=.' \
-files $WALLET_LOCATION/cwallet.sso,$WALLET_LOCATION/ewallet.p12,$TNS_ADMIN/sqlnet.ora,$TNS_ADMIN/tnsnames.ora \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:/@MY_ORACLE_DATABASE \
--table orignal_schema.orignal_table \
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--hive-import \
--hive-table new_schema.new_table \
--num-mappers 1 \
--hive-overwrite \
--mapreduce-job-name my_sqoop_job \
--delete-target-dir \
--target-dir /hdfs://myserver/apps/hive/warehouse/new_schema.db \
--create-hive-table
```

Comment: Couple of observations 1. do your user have acess to $TNS_ADMIN location? 2. can  you pls use `--hive-database new_schema` and `--hive-table new_table` ? 3. i think `--target_dir` should be like this `--target-dir /hdfs://myserver/apps/hive/warehouse/new_schema/new_table` a directory rather than a file.

Comment: Thank you for replying back. Yes I do have access to TNS. Heres my update, I created a new file with just first 3 lines (excluding my bin bash comment) and I still get the no such file or directly. I rebuilt my oracle wallet but no go. Maybe it doesnt like my wallet path?

Comment: I think you can check this too - if hive hdfs file location is a problem, then you can use sqoop like `sqoop eval --connect` to test out the connection. If it fails then its a sure oracle wallet file issue. And if it doesnt fail then, its hdfs permission issue.